# RegEx to parse MIME Message bodies in between. How?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, deno

I'm writing an IMAP4 backup app. After much research I have found the correct IMAP command to return all messages or a range of messages.

```
SS01 UID FETCH 1:* BODY[]
```

This beautiful command returns data in to following format:

```
* 1 FETCH (UID 2 BODY[] {7765}
data to be extracted
from here! which can possibly contain
) <--- one or more prior to its final...
)
* 2 FETCH (UID 3 BODY[] {443}
data to be extracted
from here! which can possibly contain
) <--- one or more prior to its final...
)
* 3 FETCH (UID 4 BODY[] {4432}
data to be extracted
from here! which can possibly contain
) <--- one or more prior to its final...
)
* 4 FETCH (UID 5 BODY[] {123}
data to be extracted
from here! which can possibly contain
) <--- one or more prior to its final...
)
SS01 OK Success
```

The only unique patterns I am able to find in this text are:

**The very first message begins with...**

```
1 FETCH (UID 2 BODY[] {7765}
```

**Each message that is not the last ends with....**

```
)
* 2 FETCH (UID 3 BODY[] {443}
```

**The last message ends with...**

```
)
SS01 OK Success
```

I have found the following example on the site that I am trying to implement but with no success.

The RegEx pattern is:

```
(?<=This is)(.*)(?=sentence)
```

Here's is a minimum reproducible example that doesn't work.

```
(\*\s\d+\s\w+\s\(UID\s\d+\sBODY\[\]\s\{\d+\})(.*\n)(\)\n\*\s\d+\s\w+\s\(UID\s\d+\sBODY\[\]\s\{\d+\})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
/\* \d+ FETCH \(UID \d+ BODY\[] {\d+}\s*([\s\S]*?)(?=\)[\r\n]+(?:\* \d+ FETCH \(UID \d+ BODY\[] {\d+}|SS01 OK Success))/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mHzn7A/1). Or, if you do not need to check all the context so thoroughly, use

```js
/{\d+}\s*([\s\S]*?)(?=\))/g
```

*Details*:

- `\* \d+ FETCH \(UID \d+ BODY\[] {\d+}` - `*`, space, one or more digits, space, `FETCH`, space, `(UID`, space, 1+ digits, space, `BODY[]`, space, `{`, one or more digits, `}`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([\s\S]*?)` - Group 1 (the value you need to get): any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `(?=\)[\r\n]+(?:\* \d+ FETCH \(UID \d+ BODY\[] {\d+}|SS01 OK Success))` - a positive lookahead that requires the following pattern sequence immediately to the right of the current location:

  - `\)` - a `)` char
  - `[\r\n]+` - one or more CR or LF chars
  - `(?:\* \d+ FETCH \(UID \d+ BODY\[] {\d+}|SS01 OK Success)` - either of

    - `\* \d+ FETCH \(UID \d+ BODY\[] {\d+}` - `*`, space, one or more digits, space, `FETCH`, space, `(UID`, space, 1+ digits, space, `BODY[]`, space, `{`, one or more digits, `}`
    - `|` - or
    - `SS01 OK Success` - a `SS01 OK Success` string.

JavaScript demo:

```js
const rx = /\* \d+ FETCH \(UID \d+ BODY\[] {\d+}\s*([\s\S]*?)(?=\)[\r\n]+(?:\* \d+ FETCH \(UID \d+ BODY\[] {\d+}|SS01 OK Success))/g;
const text = '* 1 FETCH (UID 2 BODY[] {7765}\ndata to be extracted\nfrom here!\n)\n* 2 FETCH (UID 3 BODY[] {443}\ndata to be extracted\nfrom here!\n)\n* 3 FETCH (UID 4 BODY[] {4432}\ndata to be extracted\nfrom here!\n)\n* 4 FETCH (UID 5 BODY[] {123}\ndata to be extracted\nfrom here!\n)\nSS01 OK Success';
const matches = [...text.matchAll(rx)];
console.log(Array.from(matches,x => x[1].trim()));

// Or, with the simplified regex:
console.log(
   Array.from(text.matchAll(/{\d+}\s*([\s\S]*?)(?=\))/g), x => x[1].trim())
)
```

Comment: I don't know just how you've presumed I needed to account for the boundary character `)` inside the body of the email but, you've nailed it.

Answer (score 3):

You can greatly simplify your regex like so:

```
\{\d+\}$[\r\n]+([\s\S]+?)^\)$
```

- `\{\d+\}$` - find `{digits}` at the end of a line
- `[\r\n]+` - capture any new lines
- `([\s\S]+?)` - loosely capture the desired text leading up to: (read the following bullet point)
- `^\)$` - find a line with nothing more than a closing parenthesis `)`

Your desired text will be in capture group #1

https://regex101.com/r/A86eEv/1/

```js
var regex = /\{\d+\}$[\r\n]+([\s\S]+?)^\)$/gm;

var text = `* 1 FETCH (UID 2 BODY[] {7765}
data to be extracted
from here!
)
* 2 FETCH (UID 3 BODY[] {443}
data to be extracted
from here!
)
* 3 FETCH (UID 4 BODY[] {4432}
data to be extracted
from here!
)
* 4 FETCH (UID 5 BODY[] {123}
data to be extracted
from here!
)
SS01 OK Success`;

var matches = [...text.matchAll(regex)];
console.log(Array.from(matches,x => x[1].trim()));
```